# Как принимать изменения на стороне сервера React

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, axios

**Здравствуйте! У меня есть приложение на React, которое выводит новости на главную страницу.**
У меня есть фейковые данные в json файле, к которым axios обращается. Если я добавлю новый объект с новостью и сохраню, то у меня перезагружается страница (не понятно почему). Мне нужно, чтобы при добавлении новой новости React об этом узнавал и рендерил страницу снова. 
Например **Вконтакте**: 
`Когда какое-либо сообщество делает пост, то в ленте появляется кнопка "Показать новые новости".` 
Как это реализовывается?

Обновление:
Просмотрел вкладку `Сеть` при просмотре ленты Вконтакте. Заметил, что через какой-то период происходят запросы на один и тот же сервер. Если реализовать, делая постоянные запросы, не будет ли это нагружать сервер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно спаммить постоянными запросами на сервер.
Это делается через WebSockets

Comment: Именно через сокеты реализовывается подобное или есть ещё способы?

Comment: Есть еще WebRTC